# Why package.json doesn't use the predefined values from .npmrc file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, package.json

Windows 10 x64

According [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc) info I created the `C:\Users\bushm\.npmrc` file with content:

```
author = "Andrey Bushman"
```

but when I launch the `npm init -y` command inside of new directory I see in `package.json` the property `author` is empty:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Also, I did it through the command: `npm config set author "Andrey Bushman"` but I get the same result...

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think author is a supported option for the npmrc file.
Please take a look at [this documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config) for available options.

> DESCRIPTION
>
> npm gets its config settings from the command line,
> environment variables, and npmrc files.
>
> The npm config command can be used to update and edit the contents of
> the user and global npmrc files.
>
> **For a list of available configuration options, see [npm-config](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config)**.

Comment: My local .npmrc is for me only. I try to use it by process of creating of new `package.json` files with initialized some properties, because I would likw not to write the same values each time when I create `package.json` file.

Comment: The npmrc is used instead of values in the package.json and limited to a certain set of option. I've only used the npmrc for configuring a scoped package this npmrc sits in the project next to the package and the other usage for me is storing credentials (hash) which goes in the user dir npmrc.

If you have to repeatedly create new projects with the same settings I would either copy/paste one or create a simple (node) cli tool wrapping npm init and than setting the values that can't be set using the npmrc file.

Comment: @AndreyBushman I've updated my answer quoting the docs pointing to the page I linked before, those options are available via npmrc.

Comment: Thank you. I am to use `init-author-name` instead of `author`.